# Creating a new column in a data frame with yoy - change in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I guess I haven't fully understood the transform function for data frames yet.
I want to build a new index (new column) which begins at 100 and increases in value by multiplying the first value (100) by "1+delta". The next value will be the value just calculated increased by "1+delta" etc.

Here is my example:

```
x = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)   
delta = c(0.04,0.05,0.08,0.1,0.01,0.02)   
df = data.frame(x,delta)

df = transform(df, z=c(100,z[-2]*(1+df$delta[-1])))
```

The expected outcome should be in order:

```
     x    delta        z
1 2000          NA 100.0000
2 2001  0.04000000 104.0000
3 2002  0.05000000 109.2000
4 2003  0.08000000 117.9360
5 2004  0.10000000 129.7296
6 2005  0.01000000 131.0269
7 2006  0.02000000 133.6474
```

I edited the problem, so that it is easier to understand.

The code should produce the values shown in my example but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?
How do I know where to begin counting/iterating, in other words `[-1]` or `[-2]` or...?

Many thanks in advance to this awesome community!

Comment: Can you rewrite this so it makes sense?  If you don't have `y` how do you expect to get those values out of thin air?    Let me also point out that  `?transform` specifically recommends standard subsetting (e.g.  `foo[,1] <-foo[,1]*-1`) rather than `transform` .

Comment: You don't produce y out of thin air if you just defined the base (being 100) and increment it by a certain percentage. In Excel this is quite easy but I want to know how to do it in R.

Comment: Oh, in that case, please read the R-Intro (available at CRAN and fine R-websites everywhere) and learn the language before posting.  All you want here is `y <- 100 + seq(0,X,length=Z)` where `X` is the max increment and `Z` is the number of elements desired in your result vector.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. And well yes, I am an amateur in R and pretty new to the language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is rather simple:

```
x = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)   
delta = c(0.04,0.05,0.08,0.1,0.01,0.02)   
df = data.frame(x,delta)

delta2 = 1+delta
z = 100*cumprod(delta2)
z
```

I used the function cumprod(x) to return the desired z vector. Of course, it may be possible that there is a better way to write this.